# SQL - Calculating a sum for each row in a nested select statement

Tags: sql, select, sum, subquery

this probably has a rather simple solution but I've been struggling a while now and can't find a solution due to being very new to SQL. I'm currently writing a view in which I want to add a nested select statement to calculate a KPI for each row using a SUM function. The SUM works fine, but it sums *all* values instead of the values in each row. I've tried using a CTE and window function but I can't get it to work properly.

My code is:

```
SELECT
some variables as some aliases
...
, (SELECT SUM([EK_NETTO]+[F_PORTO]+[F_DIFFERENZ_OK])
        FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF]
        WHERE [REKO_ID] IN('FAKTRG', 'OFFRG', 'PORTO', 'DIFFOK')
    ) as [gross_purchase_amount]
FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF]
```

This is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg3Nl.png

As you can see, the value is the same for each supplier.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about a column that is just `[EK_NETTO]+[F_PORTO]+[F_DIFFERENZ_OK]` without the subquery?

Comment: In principal this works, but I only want to sum values when the where condition is satisfied, so I figured I'd use a subquery to achieve that...
Edit: I need multiple calculations with different where clauses like in the one above, so after the code there will be several more like it with different values being summed and different where clauses being satisfied. I'm not sure how to achieve it in a different way so I'm thankful for any input!

Comment: Multiply it by a case where 1 for true 0 for false

Comment: you need to have some column that joins the sum subquery and F_WARENEINKAUF.

Comment: You need to add a column from your row in the subquery, so the subquery would only find items that matches the main row.

Comment: @ThiagoColebrusco I would like to manage to do it this way as well, but right now I'm not getting the right results using this:

,(SELECT SUM(w1.[EK_NETTO]+w1.[F_PORTO]+w1.[F_DIFFERENZ_OK])
   FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF] w1 join [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF] w2 on w1.[LIEFERANT_NR] = w2.[LIEFERANT_NR]
   WHERE w1.[REKO_ID] IN('FAKTRG', 'OFFRG', 'PORTO', 'DIFFOK')
  ) as [gross_purchase_amount2]

I'm trying to join them via the supplier ID ([LIEFERANT_NR]) but I get the same value for each supplier once again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably more efficient if you join to the summary.

The queries below assume that the common field is the local_supplier_code.

```
SELECT
...
, q.[gross_purchase_amount]
FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF] t
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT local_supplier_code
    , SUM([EK_NETTO]+[F_PORTO]+[F_DIFFERENZ_OK]) AS gross_purchase_amount
    FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF]
    WHERE [REKO_ID] IN ('FAKTRG', 'OFFRG', 'PORTO', 'DIFFOK')
    GROUP BY local_supplier_code
) q ON q.[local_supplier_code] = t.[local_supplier_code]
```

Or you could use an `APPLY`

```
SELECT
...
, a.[gross_purchase_amount]
FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF] t
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT SUM([EK_NETTO]+[F_PORTO]+[F_DIFFERENZ_OK]) AS gross_purchase_amount
    FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF] t2
    WHERE t2.[local_supplier_code] = t.[local_supplier_code]
      AND [REKO_ID] IN ('FAKTRG', 'OFFRG', 'PORTO', 'DIFFOK')
) a
```

Or use a `SUM OVER`
However, this method only works if the summed records are in the result.

```
SELECT
...
, SUM(CASE
      WHEN [REKO_ID] IN ('FAKTRG', 'OFFRG', 'PORTO', 'DIFFOK')
      THEN [EK_NETTO]+[F_PORTO]+[F_DIFFERENZ_OK]
      ELSE 0
      END) OVER (PARTITION BY [local_supplier_code]) AS [gross_purchase_amount]
FROM [RDWH].[dbo].[F_WARENEINKAUF] t
```

Comment: Cool. Btw, I've added a 3th option.

Comment: 3rd option works like a charm as well, thank you!

Comment: ok, just be sure you understand how a window function works. It uses the data of the result. So if you'd change your query to filter out f.e. 'FAKTRG' then that calculation would be wrong.